# Htaccess IP/Offline

Tags: .htaccess

How can I modify this htaccess file to exclude visitors with 2 different Ip addresses from being sent to the offline page? Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/offline.php$
RewriteRule .* /offline.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/offline.php$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(192\.168\.0\.2|192\.168\.0\.9)
RewriteRule .* /offline.php [L]
```

Just put your own IPs.